# <unresolved overloaded function type> when trying to pass an aggregated object's method to its class method

Tags: c++, function, pointers, call, aggregation

I have some problem compiling my code.
I have the following structure:

```
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

typedef double (*FuncType)(int );

class AnotherClass {
   public:
          AnotherClass() {};       
   double funcAnother(int i) {return i*1.0;}
};

class MyClass {
public:
         MyClass(AnotherClass & obj) { obj_ = &obj;};
    void compute(FuncType foo);
    void run();

    protected:
      AnotherClass * obj_;   /*pointer to obj. of another class */   
};

void MyClass::compute(FuncType foo) 
{
    int a=1;
    double b;
    b= foo(a);    
}

void MyClass::run()
{
     compute(obj_->funcAnother);
}

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    AnotherClass a;
    MyClass b(a);
    b.run();    

    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile it, it gives:

```
main.cpp:39:31: error: no matching function for call to ‘MyClass::compute(<unresolved overloaded function type>)’
main.cpp:30:6: note: candidate is: void MyClass::compute(double (*)(int))
```

What's wrong here?

p/s/ `AnotherClass * obj_;` should stay like that because I write some function to the big library and can't change it.

-------------- working version by Benjamin -------

```
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;


class AnotherClass {
   public:
          AnotherClass() {};       
   double funcAnother(int i) {return i*1.0;}
};


struct Foo
{

    /*constructor*/
    Foo(AnotherClass & a) : a_(a) {};

    double operator()(int i) const
    {
        return a_.funcAnother(i);
    }          

    AnotherClass & a_;               
};


class MyClass {
public:
         MyClass(AnotherClass & obj) { obj_ = &obj;};

    template<typename FuncType>     
    void compute(FuncType foo);
    void run();

   protected:
      AnotherClass * obj_;   /*pointer to obj. of another class */   
};

template<typename FuncType>
void MyClass::compute(FuncType foo) 
{
    int a=1;
    double b;
    b= foo(a);    
}

void MyClass::run()
{
    Foo f(*obj_);
    compute(f);
}

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    AnotherClass a;
    MyClass b(a);
    b.run();    

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you everybody very much for the help!

Comment: Please post a minimal offending example. The error is not caused by the code you show us.

Comment: Please post real code (cut down to a minimal example), not pseudo-code.

Comment: Looks like you declared `funcAnother` as a member function. If you make it a `static` class function it should work. Of course if it references it won't work and you need a different approach.

Comment: Reproduce the problem in a minimal program, then post the complete real code.

Comment: there is no member fucntion `void run()` in the `class MyClass`. Also the `AnotherClass` is to be defined(or atleast forward declared) before `MyClass`

Comment: ok rewrote it to the small program and the error is exacatly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function class will match the signature of your FuncType:

```
struct Foo
{
    AnotherClass & a_;
    Foo(AnotherClass & a) a_(a) {}

    double operator()(int i) const
    {
        return a_.funcAnother(i);
    }
};
```

Change MyClass::compute to a template, thusly:

```
template<typename FuncType>
void MyClass::compute(FuncType foo) 
{
    int a=1;
    foo(a);
}
```

Then you can call run like this:

```
void MyClass::run()
{
    compute(Foo(*obj_));
}
```

If your compiler supports lambdas (and there's a good chance it does), then you can forgo the function class and simply define run like this:

```
void MyClass::run()
{
    auto f = [this](int i) {
        return obj_->funcAnother(i);
    };

    compute(f);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since,

```
funcAnother(int i);
```

is a member function it passes an implicit `this` and then the prototype does not match the type of your function pointer.

The typedef for pointer to member function should be:

```
typedef double (AnotherClass::*funcPtr)(int);
```

**[Here](http://www.ideone.com/DZ5Qj)** is a modified compilable version of your code. Please check the comments inline to understand the changes, Also I left out the other details, you can add that up.

Comment: so how should I modify my pointer so it is with accordance to the function I want to call?

Comment: This is probably not the error (but this is an error with the provided code nonetheless). The error comes from trying to assign an overloaded function name to a function pointer.

Comment: @Denis: Updated the answer. You need to do following: 1. Post the **actual** sample code, 2. Post **complete** sample, The update above solves **one** of  the errors seen in your code, It does not solve **the error** which you posted, That is probably because you have ambiguous overloaded functions inside your class and you are trying to use them.

Comment: I updated the code. Also tried your solution, but it does not solve the problem, still have 'unresolved overloaded function' error.

Comment: @Denis: Updaed the answer, Follow the link to get the compilable version of your code.

Comment: Your version doesn't actually call the function though.  To do so, you'd need to pass in a reference to the actual object.

Comment: @Als, I checked your correction, it does compile, but how do I run foo function inside 'compute'? I tried 'double res = foo(a);' but it does not work;

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley Indeed you are correct, function is not called. But I don't understand why, the object is initialized, so what is the reason for .run function not to be called? I tried initializing MyClass with 'MyClass(AnotherClass * obj) { obj_ = obj;};' but i still don't have run executed.

Comment: @Denis: `run` is called, and within that, so is `compute`, but the `funcAnother` is not, nor could it be, without an object of `AnotherClass` to act upon.

Comment: @Benjamin but i do have 'AnotherClass a; MyClass b(a);', so these object are there. And I just debuged it and funcAnother is called.

Comment: @Benjamin (i'm talking about functors version, not function pointers). I just realized you must be talking about the correction of Als?

Comment: Alok, is there a way to define a templated version of functions taking  arguments which are member functions so that it automatically deduces the `AnotherClass::`?