# C++: "unresolved overload function type" between classes

Tags: c++, class, function, pointers

This is probably something elementary, I have a function from one class (called `cell`) with identifier `woo_func_ptr` taking a pointer to function of type `void` with no arguments (`void (*void_ptr)(void)`) (which I `typedef`). In another class, I have an object of `cell` and I use the method `woo_func_ptr`. It won't allow me to, I get the error in the above title. If these two functions were not embedded inside a class, they would work fine

```
typedef void (*void_ptr)(void);



double WOO{0};

struct cell {
void woo_func_ptr(void_ptr jo)
{
    jo();
}
};


class woosah
{
public:
void woo_func()
{
    WOO+=rand();
    std::cout << WOO << std::endl;
};

void run()
{
    // other stuff
    temp_cell.woo_func_ptr(woo_func);
    // yet more stuff
}

cell temp_cell;
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015362/unresolved-overloaded-function-type-when-trying-to-pass-an-aggregated-objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0x1aatf(v=vs.80).aspx shows similar errors and their fixes.

Answer (score 3):

First of all pointer to woosah member function should be declared as

```
  typedef void (woosah::*void_ptr)(void);
```

and then compiler would complain that it needs to see woosah definition while parsing this statement.

If you let compiler parse class woosah first by moving it up then it will complain that type cell is not defined (since it is contained within woosah). That wil still not solve your problem because of cyclic dependency while parsing.

One way is to solve cyclic dependency is by making **temp_cell** a pointer to cell instance and have it contained within woosah.

Also note, the syntax to call member function is by using .* or ->*

```
      void run()
      {
          // other stuff
          temp_cell->woo_func_ptr(temp_cell->*woo_func); // assuming temp_cell is pointer to some cell instance
         // yet more stuff
       }
```

Answer (score 2):

A member function is not like a regular function. That's why there's a seperate "pointer to member function" type. It's because member functions are passed the implicit `this` pointer.

In fact, the standard even limits (severly) the casting of pointer to member function.

That's the source of your error.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a static class function...

Change

```
void woo_func()
```

to

```
static void woo_func()
```

This will of coarse may not be what you want if you are trying to access data members of a particular object.

Member functions are kind of special and should not be treated as normal functions.